# Android swipe gesture with Layout following finger's movement

Tags: java, android, android-layout, swipe, gesture

I have a problem in my Android application : in one of my activity i had to create an incremental LinearLayout dinamically, and here i had no problem.

Once this Layout has been filled with data i want to let the user to swipe left or wipe right on it with the finger and catch this movement to do something and also this was quite simple.

My problem is that I want to move this Layout as soon as the user touch it and that is not only caught the gesture (at the moment, my Layout is fixed in the middle of the screen without any movement) ; my idea is to move the Layout with the same movement as the finger to the right or left edge of the screen and then catch the right/left swipe for doing other things. I'm not so skilled with animation so I hope in you! Thanks!

Comment: are you just wanting to move the layout only right and left or you wan the layout to move up and down also?

Comment: do you want the actual view to be bigger than your screen? the the user basically moves his pov arround in a much bigger view? Think of this as a chess field with the actual window being as big as a single field. Or do you want to show a completely different view, once the user swiped, as in tabs?

Comment: I want that my layout could move only left/right and, not up and down and, if possible, i wish that when, dragging the layout, it reaches the left/right edge of the screen, something happens (i.e. i could call a function that creates another layout in the center of the screen like i do at the start)